# How to assemble wavefront .obj data into element and vertex arrays of minimal size?

Tags: c++, vertex, .obj, wavefront, vertex-array

I'm having trouble putting the data inside a wavefront .obj file together.

These are the `vec3` and `vec2` definitions

```
template <typename T>
struct vec3 {
    T x;
    T y;
    T z;
};
template <typename T>
    struct vec2 {
    T x;
    T y;
};
```

Used in a vector:

```
+-----------------------------------+--------------+--------------+-------+
| std::vector<vec3<uint32_t>> f_vec | 0            | 1            | (...) |
+-----------------------------------+--------------+--------------+-------+
|                                   | v_vec_index  | v_vec_index  | (...) |
|                                   +--------------+--------------+-------+
|                                   | vt_vec_index | vt_vec_index | (...) |
|                                   +--------------+--------------+-------+
|                                   | vn_vec_index | vn_vec_index | (...) |
+-----------------------------------+--------------+--------------+-------+
```

Where:

- `v_vec_index` is an index of `std::vector<vec3<float>> v_vec` with its fields containing vertex x, y and z coordinates
- `vt_vec_index` is an index of `std::vector<vec2<float>> vt_vec` containing texture u and v coordinates
- `vn_vec_index` is an index of `std::vector<vec3<float>> vn_vec` with normal x, y and z coordinates

Every `f_vec` field is used to create a sequence of `vert_x, vert_y, vert_z, tex_u, tex_v, norm_x, norm_y, norm_z` float values inside `std::vector<float> vertex_array`.

Also, every index of `f_vec`'s field is by default a value of `std::vector<uint32_t>> element_array` - that is it contains the range of integers from `0` to `f_vec.size() - 1`.

The problem is `vec3` fields inside `f_vec` may repeat. So in order to assemble only the unique sequences mentioned above I planned to turn something like this:

```
+-----------------+---+---+---+---+---+
|      f_vec      | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
+-----------------+---+---+---+---+---+
|                 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 3 | 4 |
|                 +---+---+---+---+---+
|                 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 5 |
|                 +---+---+---+---+---+
|                 | 2 | 4 | 2 | 4 | 5 |
+-----------------+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Into this:

```
+------------------------+-----------------+---+---+---+---+---+
| whatever that would be |      index      | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
+------------------------+-----------------+---+---+---+---+---+
|                        |       key       | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 2 |
|                        +-----------------+---+---+---+---+---+
|                        |                 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 3 | 4 |
|                        |                 +---+---+---+---+---+
|                        | vec3 of indices | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 5 |
|                        |                 +---+---+---+---+---+
|                        |                 | 2 | 4 | 2 | 4 | 5 |
+------------------------+-----------------+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Where every time an element of `f_vec` would be put into the "`whatever container`"

- It would be checked if it is unique
- If it is then it would be pushed to the end of the `container` with its key being the next natural number after the biggest key - the key's value would be pushed to the `element_array` and new vertex would be created inside `vertex_array`
- If it isn't then it would be pushed to the end of the `container` with its key being the same as the key of its duplicate - the key's value would be pushed to the `element_array` but `vertex_array` would remain unchanged

How am I supposed to do it?